# Bootstrap 5 collapsed nav icon didn't automatically align to the far right after .navbar-brand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Problem:** Collapsed nav icon didn't align to the far right and instead align to the left and below h1 when the screen width is less than 700px. I am currently using bootstrap 5.

[Image before resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR3J4.png)

**Expected result:** Collapsed nav icon align to the far right and position on the same row as h1

[Image expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPniM.png)

Entire Code: https://codepen.io/kwong148/pen/xxYmGbE

Thank you

```
<header>
  <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="float-start d-none d-md-block d-xl-block">
          <div id="logo-img" alt=""Logo image"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a href="index.html"><h1>David Chu's China Bistro</h1></a>
                         
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <p>
            <img src="images/star-k-logo.png" alt="Kosher certification">
            <span>Kosher Certified</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your elements are hierarchically out of order. I would compare once again your code with the examples given at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/#image-and-text
Also, check out https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors

For example, your logo should be contained within the navbar-brand div, not above it, as in the following. (Or perhaps, you meant to include two logos?):

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="/docs/5.2/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
      Bootstrap
    </a>
```

On the other hand, the navbar-toggler button shouldn't be within the navbar-brand div. What I would do is copy one of the templates given on Bootstrap's Navbar example page and then modify it.

Below is a complete example with Navbar brand on the left and the toggle right-align. In this example, the navbar-brand is applied directly to a link rather than a div. In either case, the navbar-toggler button is a sibling to that element, not a child, and whatever is going to be collapsed is contained within a div with the classes "collapse navbar-collapse" and the toggler data-bs-target id (id="navbarTogglerDemo02") applied.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <img src="/docs/5.2/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
  Bootstrap
</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The most common problem with Bootstrap is not reading the documentation.  +1